# Toggling GeolocationMarker() in Google Maps, once setMap(null) is completed it won't turn back on

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to figure out why GeolocationMarker() responds differently than a normal marker.

With a simple marker you can toggle it on and off using marker.setMap(map) and marker.setMap(null). But when I do this with a GeoMarker, once I turn it off I can't get it to turn back on consistently.

```
controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (content == 'zoomIn') {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    } else if (content == 'zoomOut') {
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
    } else if (content == 'myGeolocation') {
        //If there is no GeolocationMarker, this makes one and turns it on.
        if (watchRunning == 0) {
            GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker({
                enableHighAccuracy: false
            });
            GeoMarker.setMap(map);
            watchRunning = 1;
            document.getElementById(content).style.backgroundColor =
                'rgba(30, 144, 255,.8)';
            document.getElementById("imgGeolocation").src =
                "geolocation_white.png";
            //If the GeolocationMarker is on, this turns it off.
        } else if (watchRunning == 1) {
            GeoMarker.setMap(null);
            document.getElementById(content).style.backgroundColor =
                'rgba(255,255,255,.7)';
            document.getElementById("imgGeolocation").src =
                "geolocation_black.png";
            watchRunning = 2;
            //If the GeolocationMarker is off, this should turn it back on.
        } else {
            GeoMarker.setMap(map);
            document.getElementById(content).style.backgroundColor =
                'rgba(30, 144, 255,.8)';
            document.getElementById("imgGeolocation").src =
                "geolocation_white.png";
            watchRunning = 1;
        };
    }
})
```

This should show it on the map...

```
GeoMarker.setMap(map);
```

And this should hide it...

```
GeoMarker.setMap(null);
```

All of these things work correctly, at first.  The problem is when the user toggles the on/off a few times. The GeoMarker will not consistently turn back on. I can usually get it to work once or twice, after that it will not turn back on.

Any thoughts on why this may be happening? I understand that placing it in the Event Listener isn't the ideal place for the actual function, but the rest of it works as far as the background and img changing.

Comment: When not using plain Google Maps API code, it's always a good idea to mention which plugin/library you are using.

Comment: Where do you declare `GeoMarker`? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. If possible, create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Btw welcome to SO.

Comment: what is `content` and where do you declare `watchRunning`?

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. I ended up taking a different route and used `watchPosition()` while placing a simple marker on the map, toggling that worked just fine. In the future I'll make sure my questions have better code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the variables are defined correctly(otherwise it wouldn't work at all) and you use this library: https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/docs/reference.html

As it seems each time when you show the marker the library will re-run the geolocation-part(what may take some time and may have undesired side-effects  ).

Possible workaround: don't toggle the `map`-property, toggle the `visibility` instead:

```
     if (watchRunning == 0) { 
        GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker({
            enableHighAccuracy: false
        });
        GeoMarker.setMap(map);

        watchRunning = 1;
        document.getElementById(content).style.backgroundColor =
            'rgba(30, 144, 255,.8)';
        document.getElementById("imgGeolocation").src =
            "geolocation_white.png";
        //If the GeolocationMarker is on, this turns it off.
    } else if (watchRunning == 1) {
        GeoMarker.setMarkerOptions({visible:false});
        GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({visible:false});
        document.getElementById(content).style.backgroundColor =
            'rgba(255,255,255,.7)';
        document.getElementById("imgGeolocation").src =
            "geolocation_black.png";
        watchRunning = 2;
        //If the GeolocationMarker is off, this should turn it back on.
    } else {
        GeoMarker.setMarkerOptions({visible:true});
        GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({visible:true});
        document.getElementById(content).style.backgroundColor =
            'rgba(30, 144, 255,.8)';
        document.getElementById("imgGeolocation").src =
            "geolocation_white.png";
        watchRunning = 1;
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the idea of switching to visibility instead of nulling it out. As I mentioned in my other comment, I decided to rebuild the program using a simple marker controlled with `watchPosition()` and `getCurrentPosition`. Clearly it didn't like having to rebuild the geolocation marker multiple times.